# TWRP unable to wipe or format `Failed to mount '/system' (Device or resource busy)`

Tags: adb, recovery-mode, twrp, file-system, lineageos

I'm trying to install [LineageOS](https://wiki.lineageos.org/devices/marlin/install) and then [GAPPS](https://wiki.lineageos.org/gapps.html) on my Pixel XL from TWRP recovery. I'll try to `Advance Wipe` the `/systems` directory and `Format Data`, but I continue to get multiple errors:

`Failed to mount '/system' (Device or resource busy)`

`Failed to mount '/vendor' (Device or resource busy)`

And

`Unable to wipe 'System'`

`Unable to wipe '/system'`

[image: to]

If I just continue with `adb sideload lineageos.zip` most of the time it stops about halfway (PowerShell shows `47%`) through and then TWRP shell  shows:

```
Installing zip file '/sideload/package.zip'
Step 1/2
Step 2/2
```

I then try to `sideload` the `gapps.zip` file and get another error saying `/system` doesn't have enough space. I've tried sideloading several different gapps versions including their smallest `pico` zip fie of `91.39 MiB`.

I am able to then boot into LineageOS, but no GAPPS show and I'm not able to run any new apps installed via APK without them crashing.

My assumption is that I need to fully wipe `system` and format it, but I've been trying for two days now and still get the above `(Device or resource busy)` errors. Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Why are you formatting `/system` and `/vendor` with FAT? That won't work, Android requires a filesystem aware of UNIX permissions. Try with `ext4` or `f2fs`.

Comment: @Lrfan Latif how do I do that? TWTP only gives me the format options, but doesn't let me choose what type of filesystem (I least that I'm aware of ).

Comment: TWRP does have Repair or Change Filesystem option in Advanced Wipe. You can also do that directly from terminal: `mkfs.ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system`. For A/B devices `system` would be either `system_a` or `system_b`. If there is no `mkfs.ext4`, look for something like `make_ext4` in `/sbin`. I don't remember exact name of binary, Android uses different than Linux.

Comment: besides the fact that TWRP think it's fat, that does not explain why it fails. busy means there are open files or folders, you must `umount -l` the device first. `mke2fs -t ext4` is the busybox applet for formatting

Comment: @alecxs what process can be using `/system` or `/vendor` in TWRP? The busy message could be because of repeated attempts, where the previous threads of `mkfs` or `fsck` could be keeping block devices busy.

Comment: @Lrfan Latif `mkfs.ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system` gives me `mkfs.ext4: not found`. When I `ls` `/sbin` I only see `mke2fs`, `mkfs.fat`, `mkexfatfs`, but nothing related to `ext4`.


@alecxs When I run `mke2fs -t ext4 /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system` I get `/dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system is mounted; will not make a filesystem here!`


But when I run `umount -l /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system` I get `unmount: not found`

Comment: OK, I booted to an earlier version of TWRP (3.2.3.1) and I was able to use TWRP's WIPE and Advance Format tools without errors! I went ahead to install the GAPPs, but I still got the `not enough space in /system` error (the error scrolls by very fest fast and then it is gone before I have time to copy its exact text). Any solution to this?

Comment: /dev/block/bootdevice/by-name/system is just a symlink to system_a or system_b - look in `df` for the partition mounted on /system, repeat `umount -l /system` for all folders where it is mounted. For some devices TWRP requires mounted /system /vendor or /modem for decrypting /data because TWRP uses binaries from device. Other reasons can be multiple mounts or just a open `cd` from shell. `adb pull /tmp/recovery.log` will give you details about failed install. use the pico package

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I fixed this by using an older version of TWRP (3.2.3.1), then I downloaded GAPPs from a [different source](http://downloads.codefi.re/jdcteam/javelinanddart/gapps) and installed using `adb sideload` now all is working.

Comment: Thanks! I had this same issue with TWRP v3.3.1-0. v3.2.3.1 worked!

Comment: No luck with v3.2.3.1 for me